# Is it safe to expose url endpoint which expose csrf token?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, csrf, csrf-protection

I have built a web app. The app needs to make several POST requests. Since full page reload does not happen (single page app), every time form gets generated dynamically from a template, I made the app to make a ajax GET request to the server to fetch csrf token, which later will be submitted with other form values.

To achieve, this I made a endpoint in server '/getCsrf' which returns csrf token to the user. Every time the endpoint is visited, different unique csrf token gets generated.

Is approach described above safe? I was wondering if attacker can force victim to visit that '/getCsrf' url in different server, steal 'csrf' token data, load the fabricated form page, and send an unexpected POST request to the server.

Comment: The CSRF token is always visible to the client anyway, it's not a secret, the point is that it changes and is sent back to verify that the request was authentic. Why you would use an endpoint to create the CSRF token is beyond me, and I'm not even sure how you'd validate that across different clients, but if you can make it work, sure !

Comment: The webpage is all AJAX based, so full page refresh never happens. Users can still make multiple POST requests, so I need a create an endpoint which allows clients to fetch new CSRF token. CSRF token is persisted at session level.

Comment: Then you send the CSRF token back with each ajax request, it's a common way to do this, but usually the token is outputted in the HTML to authenticate that the user is making the request, not someone else on behalf of that user, and using an endpoint would probably make it easier for someone to just make a request to that endpoint and get the same token, depending on how you do it ?